# Canvas drawing errors (HTML5 and JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I can usually research my problem and get an answer from someone else's mistake but this time i am having a rather unusual time finding an answer. The concept is that you can colorize `32x32` "pixels" on a `16x16` grid. My complete code follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jscolor.js"></script>
    <title>Tiles</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" height="512" width="512" onclick="draw(window.event)">
        Oops, you don't have Canvases
    </canvas>
    <input type="text" value="000000" class="color"></input>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var draw_a = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        function draw(e) {
            draw_a.fillStyle = "#" + document.getElementById("color").value;
            draw_a.fillRect(
                math.floor( e.clientX / 16 ),
                math.floor( e.clientX / 16 ),
                32,
                32
            );
        }
        draw_a.fillStyle = "#000000";
        draw_a.fillRect( 0 , 0 , 512 , 512 );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Alnitak It is nonfunctional and i would like someone to correct me.

Comment: define "non functional".

Comment: @Alnitak Well, It refuses to color any other pixel

Comment: `math.floor` JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

You're dividing and rounding the click coordinates, but not multiplying the value back up again to map to canvas coordinates - there should also be 32 pixels between points, not 16.

There's also no such function as `math.floor`, it should be `Math.floor`:

```
var x = 32 * Math.floor(e.clientX / 32);
var y = 32 * Math.floor(e.clientY / 32);
draw_a.fillRect(x, y, 32, 32);
```

Lastly, your color input should have an `id` of `color`, not a `class`

Working (in Chrome at least) demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/VJNdR/

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about that but it still refuses to write output saying "document.getElementById("color") is null"